# stopSelf() is not calling onDestroy()

Tags: android, service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        for (int i=0;i<150;i++)
       {
           Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+i);
           if (i==10)
           {
               stopSelf();
               Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: stop");
           }

       }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
    }
```

I am learning about Service in Android.
This is my code. When I write stopSelf(); outside the for loop it is working fine. But when written inside the loop stopSelf() is not called even when the condition is met. And the service is destroyed after completion of the loop. I searched over the internet but could not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If "the service is destroyed after completing the loop" you could stop the loop early by using the `break` statement. Try the following:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    for (int i=0;i<150;i++)
   {
       Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+i);
       if (i==10)
       {
           stopSelf();
           Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: stop");
           break; // This will stop the loop.
       }

   }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
}
```